# Maven: How to run module before building other modules in multi-module project?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a Maven POM Project that includes a number of modules.

One of them is a REST Web Service that some of the other modules use.
This module is a standalone executable.

What I am trying to achieve is to have the web service build and run before all the other modules.

<s>I understand that just by changing the order of the modules in the pom file I can get the module to build before the others, but how do I run it before building the rest of them?</s>

I need to run it so that I can perform a series of tests included in the rest of the modules.

The reason I am trying to achieve this kind of functionality is because what I'm ultimately trying to do is having the project build and test correctly on Jenkins.

Comment: If your tests need a running REST service, they should start it (or make sure that it is running). It is a test prerequisite.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your suggestion. Probably I have to update my question too. The service is a standalone executable. The tests will test if they can get back the expected results from the service. There will also be a test for which the service will not be working but in that case I can just use a false url I suppose?

Comment: The tests of you REST part should be implemented in the REST module either as unit tests ore integration tests...Defining the order by ordering modules is simply wrong..Better define dependencies between modules which results into the build order...

Comment: The dependencies do exist. Also the REST service can have its own tests but I still need to test that I am actually able to retrieve and process the data in the other modules. Also the retrieved data are further needed for the proper execution of the other modules. Without a running web service I can not test the other modules. Unfortunately the project is too large to be able to post details about its internal workings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that just by changing the order of the modules in the pom file I can get the module to build before the others, but how do I run it before building the rest of them?

Ordering of modules will **not necessarily** build them in that order. If one module depends on another then you must handle it through `<dependency>`in the pom of the dependent project.
To answer your question, build the REST service module first and deploy it to your server/container. In multimodule projects running command like `mvn somegoal` will run `somegoal` on all the modules.

To run different goals on modules, try in two steps 
`mvn -pl module1 somegoal`
`mvn -pl module2 someothergoal`
 In your project they will take the form of 
`mvn -pl RESTModule deploy` followed by usual
 mvn command for running test for other modules. Remember the -pl option for these too.
**Edit**: After looking at the requirements from your comment I tried one more solution. Might work for you as well. Add maven-deploy-plugin to the pom of REST Module and tie it to a phase such that only the RESTModule project deploys the artifacts but not others (since they don't have such plugin in their pom). snippet to be added.
`

```
<project>

    <build>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <executions>                                                 
                <execution>     
                <id>MyProjId</id>                                         
                    <phase>package</phase>                              
                    <goals>                                              
                        <goal>deploy</goal>                             
                    </goals>                                                                               
                </execution>                                             
            </executions>
              </plugin>


    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <id>my-repository</id>
          <url>http://path/to/your/repo</url>
        </repository>
      </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

and run the project using the parent pom in jenkins.

Comment: As I said in the above comments, I have the dependencies set up in each individual pom file. I suppose I should remove the phrase from my description. What I want to do is be able to build the project on Jenkins every time I commit my changes (changes are committed to Gitlab and trigger the build on Jenkins). So I need to have the project set up in such a way that the only thing you need to do in order to build everything is to actually build the parent module. Is that possible? Do you think the only way is to build the web service as a separate module?

Comment: Can you check and comment now. Not sure if SO notifies for answer edits @Arch

Comment: Thank you for your help @Abhi7950, I was able to test the command line solution using mvn and it worked, Im not sure how I will use this approach in Jenkins, but for now it looks like a viable option. I will also try to test your updated suggestion.

Comment: Just in case that anyone is interested I have to mention that I used the tomcat plugin in order to be able to properly compile and load the service on my local tomcat server.